# What is the best position for pull ups to target one's lower pecs?

Tags: muscle-gain, pull-ups, calisthenics

Palms facing same direction to your front, Palms facing back in toward you, or Palms facing each other roughly parallel to your ears?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None of these are particularly good exercises for targeting the lower pecs, as the pecs are only very minor contributors to shoulder extension (as in narrow grip pull-ups) and shoulder adduction (as in wide grip pull-ups). In all pull-up variants, the latissimus dorsi muscles do the bulk of the work, and these are likely to fatigue and prevent you from doing further reps long before the pecs receive any significant stimulus.

Exercises that actually target the lower chest include [decline bench press](https://exrx.net/WeightExercises/PectoralSternal/BBDeclineBenchPress) and [dips](https://exrx.net/WeightExercises/PectoralSternal/BWChestDip), as well as general chest exercises such as the bench press, push-ups, or pec flys, which would target the whole of the pec muscles.